# 403 Forbidden when creating a new version in Google Cloud Platform ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

Using the Python Google API client library from AppEngine flex, I'm making calls to GCP ML Engine API. 
It works fine when I list the different models, get their default version and all "read-only" actions but when I try to create a new version for a model, it does not work. I get a 403 Forbidden error with "Access to model denied".

I use a service account to make the calls. In IAM, my service account has the "ML Engine administrator" right.

This is how I make the call

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(PATH_TO_MY_JSON)
ml_client = discovery.build(u'ml', u'v1', credentials=credentials)

body = {
        u"name": version_name,
        u"description": description,
        u"runtimeVersion": current_default_version.get(u"runtimeVersion"),
        u"framework": current_default_version.get(u"framework"),
        u"pythonVersion": current_default_version.get(u"pythonVersion"),
        u"deploymentUri": deployment_uri
    }
request = ml_client.projects().models().versions().create(parent=get_query_name(model_name), body=body)
request.execute()
```

The error

```
 <HttpError 403 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXX/models/YYY/versions?alt=json returned "Access to model denied.">
```

it has to do with the service account because when I run this code in Cloud Shell and build my `ml_client` without credentials (`ml_client = discovery.build(u'ml', u'v1')`), it works fine.

Comment: Did you `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud auth application-default login` ?

Comment: not sure how this impacts the deployed version but anyway, no I did not

Comment: It could be that the service account doesn't have permissions to read the bucket. Even when the account is a Cloud ML Admin the storage permissions are required to deploy/create a model since Cloud ML needs to read the training files that are stored in such bucket. Could you confirm if you have set [the storage permissions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/access-control#permissions_required_for_storage) as stated in the doc?

Answer (score 0):

My Service Account IAM Roles:

- ML Engine Developer
- Storage Object Viewer

For me, it appears that if I created a model resource via the UI, I could not create a model version from the python client library. However, if I created a model resource via the python client, then create a model version it worked.

```
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('./service_account.json')
ml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request_dict = {
   'name': 'model_resource_name',
   'description': 'your_model_description'}

project_id = 'projects/{}'.format('YOUR_PROJECT_ID')
request = ml.projects().models().create(parent=project_id, body=request_dict)
request.execute()

body = {
   u"name": "test_version",
   u"description": "description",
   u"runtimeVersion": "1.13",
   u"framework": "TENSORFLOW",
   u"pythonVersion": "3.5",
   u"deploymentUri": "gs://BUCKET_ID/directory_path_to_your_model/"
        }

request = ml.projects().models().versions().create(
    parent='projects/{}/models/{}'.format(
          'YOUR_PROJECT_ID', 
          'model_resource'), 
    body=body)

response = request.execute()
```

Still investigating why the model resource creation via the UI doesn't allow the python client to create a model version.